# XSS prevention. Handling <script is enough?

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I was wondering if checking for and removing `"<script"` from text entry fields would be enough to stop javascript code injection attacks?

Comment: I'm happy to see that the overwhelming answer is **NO**..

Answer (score 18):

**No, blocking specific cases is not enough** - sooner or later, someone will come up with a contrived case you didn't think of.

See this [list of XSS attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) for the most common ones (other, still more exotic, may exist). You need to whitelist the allowed syntax instead of assuming that everything beside the known vectors should be OK.

Comment: +1 that link is excellent, I knew blacklisting was an impossible task, but I didn't realise quite how impossible. I wrote some very naive blacklisting code a few years ago, it would have caught very few of those attacks

Comment: @andynormancx: yup, Postel's Law strikes back: a large part of the examples is invalid markup, which gets converted byt the browser into something valid but nasty.

Comment: I particularly liked the žscriptualert(EXSSE)ž/scriptu example, when injected into a site emitting ASCII that becomes runnable code, impressive.

Answer (score 9):

It depends also on what you are doing with the input. Here is a simplified example I found on a real website of some greeting card service:

It contained a select field with which you were able to select the color of the text:

```
<select name="color">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

The value was used unfiltered on the greeting card page. So it is easy to tamper the POST data sent, and change

```
color=red
```

to something like

```
color=red%22+onload%3D%22alert(%27foo%27)
```

which would result in

```
<font color="red" onload="alert('foo')">
```

instead of `<font color="red">`.

---

So the point is never trust any input from the user, not even predefined values you define.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not, there are a variety of attacks available, for example executing JavaScript via the `<img>` element as well.  I recommend using a XSS library for whatever platform you're on server-side.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<img src="javascript:alert('hi');">
<input type="image" src="javascript:alert('hi');">
```

...not those examples themselves are harmless, but you see how there are others ways to execute JavaScript.  Which exploits work depends on the browser, but just be aware there are other methods out there.

Comment: what libraries would you recommend?

Comment: @Nick, what are those XSS library capable of doing?

Comment: @samy - it depends on the platform, I'm not sure what the OP has server-side - PHP, ASP.Net, Ruby?  @Starx - these libraries specialize in stripping out all (or *hopefully* all) of the various XSS attack methods by sanitizing the incoming HTML appropriately.

Comment: @samy – something compatible with whatever you are already using on the server side.

Comment: On .net there is the Microsoft AntiXSS library http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx that works by having a whitelist of what is allowed in attributes/HTML text, rather than a blacklist of what isn't allowed. The whitelist approach is much safer.

Comment: @NickCraver and @DavidDorward Makes sense; i was thinking along the lines of a transversal library, for example a javascript to sanitize the input, but that doesn't make sense in retrospect. @andynormancx thanks! .net is fine, so the link is appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2):

myspace was hacked because of css expressions. Blacklisting won't work, Whitelisting is the only route.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to those mentioned by Nick, you should also be on the look-out for JavaScript events, such as: "onload", "onclick",...

Answer (score 1):

`<s<scriptcript` after one removal becomes `<script`.

If you block that, there are plenty of others. It's much simpler and more correct to *escape* (not remove) all occurances `<`, `"` and `&`.

Comment: while index of "<script" != -1; but you're right about it not being the correct approach

Comment: You have to assume there's infinite number of things that launch scripts, e.g. `<img onload=`, `<span onmouseover=`, etc. Even if you somehow perfectly blacklist all that are possible today, browsers will add new ones tomorrow (this comes up in standards discussions regularly, and the answer is always "we'll add a new vector anyway, because these sites were insecure already").