# How to create an HTML document with PHP?

Tags: php, html

Yes, i want to **create** an .html or .php (whatever) document with some forms.

Example:

The user opens a page (preference: php) and see 1 form for website title and 1 button. Ok, he put the website title of your preference an click in the button. This page send the information contained in the form and create an html/php document with the title that user put in form.

This is not about to show some variables in html with "echo", is about to really **create** some new document.

Anyone?

Comment: http://php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: And where should it save? On the server itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$html = '<html>
    <head>
        <title>' . htmlspecialchars($title) . '</title>
    </head>
    <body>Some HTML</body>
</html>';
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.html', $html);
```

That will create a file for you with the title the user submitted (assuming you are submitting by POST).

Comment: I would add to this answer that OP should be aware of the destination folder permissions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283626/why-does-file-put-contents-have-permission-issues-when-run-from-the-browser?rq=1

Comment: Hurray for XSS vulnerabilities!

Comment: Hurray for uploading a backdoor

Comment: @Jack There are [plenty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) of [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344703/xss-prevention-handling-script-is-enough) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site) on SO that cover XSS. No need for me to repeat. Though I have updated my answer to at least prevent the basics.

Answer (score 2):

So your form will need to be something like

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pageTitle" id="pageTitle" />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then you will need to following code to capture the value of the page title and create the html page

```
if($_POST['formSubmit']) {
    $newpage = '<html><head><title>' . $_POST['pageTitle'] . '</title></head><body><-- Whatever you want to put here --></body></html>';
    file_put_contents('newpage.html', $newpage );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
$content = "<html><head><title>$title</title></head><body>Your content here</body></html>";

file_put_contents('index.html', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would echo the contents as usual but you should send the following headers:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.html'); //or whatever name you like here
header('Content-Type: text/html'); //or text/php if the file is php
```

This will make the browser open a download dialoug for your file